# How do I read the number of files in a folder using Python?

Tags: python, file-io

How do I read the number of files in a specific folder using Python? Example code would be awesome!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To count files and directories non-recursively you can use [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) and take its length.

To count files and directories recursively you can use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) to iterate over the files and subdirectories in the directory.

If you only want to count files not directories you can use `os.listdir` and [`os.path.file`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) to check if each entry is a file:

```
import os.path
path = '.'
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

Or alternatively using a generator:

```
num_files = sum(os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)) for f in os.listdir(path))
```

Or you can use `os.walk` as follows:

```
len(os.walk(path).next()[2])
```

I found some of these ideas from [this thread](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/45188-count-files-directory).

Answer (score 26):

`pathlib`, that is new in v. 3.4, makes like easier. The line labelled *1* makes a non-recursive list of the current folder, the one labelled *2* the recursive list.

```
from pathlib import Path

import os
os.chdir('c:/utilities')

print (len(list(Path('.').glob('*')))) ## 1
print (len(list(Path('.').glob('**/*')))) ## 2
```

There are more goodies too. With these additional lines you can see both the absolute and relative file names for those items that *are* files.

```
for item in Path('.').glob('*'):
    if item.is_file():
        print (str(item), str(item.absolute()))
```

Result:

```
boxee.py c:\utilities\boxee.py
boxee_user_catalog.sqlite c:\utilities\boxee_user_catalog.sqlite
find RSS.py c:\utilities\find RSS.py
MyVideos34.sqlite c:\utilities\MyVideos34.sqlite
newsletter-1 c:\utilities\newsletter-1
notes.txt c:\utilities\notes.txt
README c:\utilities\README
saveHighlighted.ahk c:\utilities\saveHighlighted.ahk
saveHighlighted.ahk.bak c:\utilities\saveHighlighted.ahk.bak
temp.htm c:\utilities\temp.htm
to_csv.py c:\utilities\to_csv.py
```

Comment: Equivalent of the `## 1` line with `iterdir` is `print( len(list(Path('.').iterdir())) )`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module:

```
>>> import glob
>>> print len(glob.glob('/tmp/*'))
10
```

Or, as Mark Byers suggests in his answer, if you only want files:

```
>>> print [f for f in glob.glob('/tmp/*') if os.path.isfile(f)]
['/tmp/foo']
>>> print sum(os.path.isfile(f) for f in glob.glob('/tmp/*'))
1
```

Comment: It should be said, that `os.listdir('.')` includes hidden files (starting with a single dot), whereas `glob('./*')` does not.

Comment: @lunaryorn - If you want hidden files in the current directory, use `glob('.*')`. If you want everything including hidden files, use `glob('.*') + glob('*')`.

Answer (score 6):

Mark Byer's answer is simple, elegant, and goes along with the python spirit.

**There's a problem, however**: if you try to run that for any other directory than `"."`, it will fail, since `os.listdir()` returns the names of the files, not the full path. Those two are the same when listing the current working directory, so the error goes undetected in the source above.

For example, if you are at `/home/me` and you list `/tmp`, you'll get (say) `['flashXVA67']`. You'll be testing `/home/me/flashXVA67` instead of `/tmp/flashXVA67` with the method above.

You can fix this using `os.path.join()`, like this:

```
import os.path
path = './whatever'
count = len([f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

Also, if you're going to be doing this count a lot and require performance, you may want to do it without generating additional lists. Here's a less elegant, unpythonesque yet efficient solution:

```
import os

def fcount(path):
    """ Counts the number of files in a directory """
    count = 0
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
            count += 1
            
    return count


# The following line prints the number of files in the current directory:
path = "./whatever"
print fcount(path)
```

Comment: have a look at bstpierre's answer.

Comment: Indeed! Looks better than mine, and if you're reading this, check back on the first answer, an addition was made by Mark using walk() that addresses both of the problems I pointed out in a single line.

Comment: +1 for spotting the bug - I've updated my answer with your corrected version.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('./your/folder/path'):
    print(f'There are {len(dirnames)} directories and {len(filenames)} images in {dirpath}.')
```

The result would look like this:

```
There are 10 directories and 0 images in ./asl_data/photos.
There are 0 directories and 32 images in ./asl_data/photos\0.
There are 0 directories and 34 images in ./asl_data/photos\1.
There are 0 directories and 32 images in ./asl_data/photos\2.
There are 0 directories and 31 images in ./asl_data/photos\3.
There are 0 directories and 34 images in ./asl_data/photos\4.
There are 0 directories and 31 images in ./asl_data/photos\5.
There are 0 directories and 40 images in ./asl_data/photos\6.
There are 0 directories and 33 images in ./asl_data/photos\7.
There are 0 directories and 30 images in ./asl_data/photos\8.
There are 0 directories and 39 images in ./asl_data/photos\9.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is using `pathlib` and checking the length of the result of the `iterdir()` method. For example:

```
from pathlib import Path


search_path = Path('<relative or absolute path>')
n_files = len([*search_path.iterdir()])
```

If you want only certain types of files you can customize the list comprehension:

```
# only files
n_files = len([p for p in search_path.iterdir() if p.is_file()])

# only directories
n_files = len([p for p in search_path.iterdir() if p.is_dir()])

# only given extension
ext = '.png'
n_files = len([p for p in search_path.iterdir() if p.suffix==f'{ext}'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
total = len(filter(
            lambda f: os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path_to_dir, f)),
            os.listdir(path_to_dir)))
```

OR

```
total = sum([True for f in os.listdir(path_to_dir) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join([path_to_dir, f)])
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive solution:

```
sum(len(fs) for _,_,fs in os.walk(os.getcwd()))
```

for current directory solution:

```
len(os.walk(os.getcwd()).next()[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

print(len(os.listdir(r"your path")))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).