# Count the number of files with a special suffix in a directory using python

Tags: python

It is possible to count the number of all files in a directory by:

```
 import os
 path = '/mnt/BIGDATA/'
 num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

As mentioned in [How do I read the number of files in a folder using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883138/how-do-i-read-the-number-of-files-in-a-folder-using-python)
but what I should do is to count the number of files with a special suffix in a directory using python? for example count all '???.pdf' files in a directory.

Comment: *"spacial"* - *spatial* or *special*?

Comment: Slightly better with the additional detail.  Now you just need to make an attempt yourself, post the code, and tell us what is not working.

Comment: you are already using an if statement in you list comprehension as a sort of filter, use that in the same way to filter out things with `f.endswith(` or such

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = '/mnt/BIGDATA/'
numberof_dotpdf_files=0
for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".pdf"):
            numberof_dotpdf_files=numberof_dotpdf_files+1
```