# How to make python count how many files are in a directory?

Tags: python, directory

Just by the title, you might think that this is a duplicate but it is not. I need to make my program count how many files with a specific ending such as .mp3 or .mp4 are in a directory. So if I have 10 .mp3 files in a directory I want my program to figure that out. After that, I need to list those files with numbers next to them so that the user can enter a number to launch that file. I need help with counting the files.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33635353/count-the-number-of-files-with-a-special-suffix-in-a-directory-using-python

Comment: `for file in glob.glob('/some/directory/*.mp3'):`

Comment: Great for the first part but I still need help with the number part.

Comment: btw I am taking KJH's answer if anyone is wondering. The sites posted provided clear answers.

Comment: Split the filename on the dot; feed the extensions into collections.Counter.

Comment: @wwii can I get a code example?

Comment: I need to add numbers to each filename in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os 
i=0
x=[]
for file in os.listdir():
    if file.endswith('.mp3'):
        print(file)
        x.append(file)
        i+=1
print('the total number of files: ' +str(i))
fileNumber=input('enter number')
os.startfile(x[int(fileNumber)])
```

make sure to use change directory to the folder location using `os.chdir()` or enter complete path in `os.listdir()`

Comment: I got that part the part I need help with now is adding numbers to each file and then print all the files out with those numbers. I need the numbering system so that each file is numbered in a way that a user can just enter 0 and the file labeled 0 will launch.

Comment: Also I cant ask any more questions apparently so if you guys could upvote this :)

Comment: you can use `os.startfile()'

Comment: do not worry i will edit my answer to complete your answer

Comment: i should note that programmers start count from 0

Comment: Ok if everyone could upvote this question I would be thankful because that -1 reputation on this question is not letting me ask anymore.

Comment: Is there a way to make the program show the element number when the list is printed in python?

Comment: of course,instead of `x.append(file)` use  `x.append(file,i)`